# Does Visual Studio 2015 Express for Desktop support JIT debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, jit, visual-studio-express

I've some trouble with JIT Debugging. 
In Visual Studio 2015 Express is available menu Tools->Options->Debugging->Just-In-Time? I can't see this menu in my VS -  [image]

I want use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` to invoke debugger from code when some my plugin initializing. I can't find any official document, that in VS Express 2015 JIT is not supported.

Only this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.100) tell that VS Express **2010** not supported JIT, but I use **2015**. In this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015 is some infomrmation about JIT in **2015** but not clear in version Express/Community/Pro ...

Some one know,  is **Visual Studio 2015 Express** support JIT and have some docs/ emails from MS?

Comment: Can you just try to run `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in VS Express? Are you sure, that you can't use a VS Community (it is also free)?

Comment: Now, when I use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` invoke some errors [error](https://i.imgur.com/zLbmRH3.png). The VS Community license does not allow to use them.

Comment: there is a searchbox in left-top corner of `Tools->Options` window. Search for `jit` or `just-in-time`. If no results - I think that this feature is not supported in Express edition.

Comment: Yes - no result. But this is only you feeling unfortunately no hard facts. I think similar as you, but I like facts and documentations.

Comment: I'm in doubt that this is documented somewhere. If you want facts, maybe you can try to ask [MS support](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/)?

Comment: I'll guess that the real reason is that you use Win10.  A recent update disabled WER (Windows Error Reporting) and WER is necessary to get the Debug button in the crash dialog.  You want it back on for a programmer's machine.  Still, it isn't exactly an Express-like feature, do favor Community.

Comment: I don't think so. If I run Visual Studio 2015 Integrated Shell (base of Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools), I see Just-In-Time in debugging tab, and JIT work. But from, Visual Studio 2015 Integrated Shell I can't build solution, can't use F12 etc. I think this is not operating system problem. I thing this is Express Edition limitation, but I search for proof from MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visuall Studio Express Edition just not suport JIT debugging. Must stop process for ex. some message box or timmer and then attach to process.